# Associated const to a trait in Rust not working as described in the tutorial

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to execute the same code as described [here](https://www.amazon.de/Programming-Rust-Fast-Systems-Development/dp/1492052590/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=E03GHY2KI0A1&keywords=programming%20rust&qid=1638367965&qsid=258-5569170-1732809&sprefix=Programming%20rust%2Caps%2C182&sr=8-1&sres=1492052590%2C1800560818%2C1718500440%2C1491927283%2C1718501854%2C1617294551%2CB0874JFXSD%2C1838828109%2C1484234677%2C1484251202%2C1981739270%2CB09MCJ4X2M%2C1789530660%2C1788839358%2C1119712971%2C1593278284&srpt=ABIS_BOOK)

(Page ~448)

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c86b926ecdd3dc01f309bbff3b7e3db7)

But when I try to execute this sample I get:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Float` cannot be made into an object


--> src\main.rs:35:25
   |
35 |     let fibonacci_of_3: dyn Float = fibonacci(3);
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^ `Float` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = help: consider moving `ZERO` to another trait
   = help: consider moving `ONE` to another trait
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src\maths.rs:4:11
   |
3  | pub trait Float {
   |           ----- this trait cannot be made into an object...
4  |     const ZERO: Self;
   |           ^^^^ ...because it contains this associated `const`
5  |     const ONE: Self;
   |           ^^^ ...because it contains this associated `const`
```

Here is the Fibonacci function:

```
pub fn fibonacci<T: Float + Add<Output=T>>(n: usize) -> T {
    match n {
        0 => T::ZERO,
        1 => T::ONE,
        n => fibonacci::<T>(n - 1) + fibonacci::<T>(n - 2),
    }
}
```

About the dyn, without it I get:

```
error[E0782]: trait objects must include the `dyn` keyword
  --> src\main.rs:34:25
   |
34 |     let fibonacci_of_3: Float = fibonacci(3);
   |                         ^^^^^
   |
help: add `dyn` keyword before this trait
   |
34 |     let fibonacci_of_3: dyn Float = fibonacci(3);
   |                         +++
```

Is the information outdated or am I doing something wrong?, in paper makes sense.

Regards

~M

Comment: The tutorial doesn't use `dyn Float`. Also, where is this? tuturial

Comment: Hello @ChayimFriedman, thanks for your answer I have updated my question. -> https://www.amazon.de/Programming-Rust-Fast-Systems-Development/dp/1492052590/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=E03GHY2KI0A1&keywords=programming+rust&qid=1638367965&qsid=258-5569170-1732809&sprefix=Programming+rust%2Caps%2C182&sr=8-1&sres=1492052590%2C1800560818%2C1718500440%2C1491927283%2C1718501854%2C1617294551%2CB0874JFXSD%2C1838828109%2C1484234677%2C1484251202%2C1981739270%2CB09MCJ4X2M%2C1789530660%2C1788839358%2C1119712971%2C1593278284&srpt=ABIS_BOOK

Comment: I didn't meant to omit the `dyn` but probably you want generics and not trait objects. Trait objects indeed cannot have associated consts. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Looks then a contradiction of this book, so, constants associated in traits are not allowed?

Comment: @MarcoTulioAvilaCerón, could you please remove the images and write the code itself? Also it is usually helpful to use https://play.rust-lang.org to post an example of your code

Comment: Ok, I will do that, one moment

Comment: @MarcoTulioAvilaCerón They are allowed, as long as you don't try to create a trait object.

Comment: Hello all, I updated the link to play.rust-lang.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ***specify the types*** (not the trait itself) you want to use:

```rust
use std::ops::Add;

trait Float {
    const ZERO: Self;
    const ONE: Self;
}

impl Float for f32 {
    const ZERO: f32 = 0.0;
    const ONE: f32 = 1.0;
}

impl Float for f64 {
    const ZERO: f64 = 0.0;
    const ONE: f64 = 1.0;
}

fn fibonacci<T: Float + Add<Output=T>>(n: usize) -> T {
    match n {
        0 => T::ZERO,
        1 => T::ONE,
        n => fibonacci::<T>(n - 1) + fibonacci::<T>(n - 2),
    }
}

fn main() {
   let fibonacci_of_3: f32 = fibonacci::<f32>(3);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d4575f82384afe198458f8736b97ae5b)

Notice that you can not use `dyn Float`. The compiler do not know how to build the vtable for that trait, as it do not have any methods at all.

Comment: Thanks so much, classical answer, "why I didn't see it before" :)